# How to show this polynomial is less than zero?

Tags: polynomials

$$
f(y)=Ny(y-1)^2-y-y^{2N+3}+y^{N+1}\left (N^2y^3+(-2N^2+N+1)y^2+(N^2-2N)y+N+1 \right )
$$
where $N$ is an integer bigger or equal to 2, and $y>1$.How to show $f(y)<0$? Any hint?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Eww, where did this polynomial come from? I'd start with the substitution $y=x+1$ and see if that leads anywhere...

Comment: Rewrite as $Ny(y-1)^2-y-y^{2N+3}+y^{N+1}(N^2y(y-1)^2+N(y-1)^2+1)$ for a start

Comment: I think we should factor out the $y$, as it does not change the sign.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I think an $y^{N+3}$ is missing.